# É possível adicionar o Expo à um projeto existente?

Tags: react-native, expo

Gostaria de saber se é possível adicionar o Expo à um projeto React Native que já existe.

Na documentação do Expo só encontrei para criar um projeto do zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Infelizmente não é possível, pois o Expo te oferece todo um workflow em um ambiente de desenvolvimento um pouco diferente que o **react-native-cli**. Tanto é que uma vez que o projeto for ejetado do Expo (`expo eject`) você terá de criar um novo projeto com Expo (`expo init`) para desenvolver.